# Proof of the linearity of expectation for continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

All the demonstrations I found  of the linearity of the expectation in the continuous case start like this :

$$
\mathsf E(X+Y) = \iint (x+y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,dx \,dy
$$

I don't understand why the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ can be used here. Does it means that the density probability function of $X+Y$ is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ ?

Comment: This is the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Joint_distributions) applied to the function $g(x,y)=x+y$.

Comment: @md5 what? i believe the point is to understand how LOTUS for single variable applies to 2 or more variables. actually what's, like, the original here? $E[X] = \int x f_X(x) dx$ and so based on this original thing we get LOTUS $E[g(X)] = \int g(x) f_X(x) dx$. what's the original thing from w/c we get $E[g(X,Y)] = \int g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y) dA$ ?

Comment: The answer of Graham Kemp is correct both mathematically and philosophically! The simple '$Z=X+Y$' answers precisely the question of how joint density comes up, W/C CAN STILL be asked even if i know LOTUS i.e. i think each one of Michael Hardy and md5 incompletely explains/explain (grammar?) how LOTUS applies: the answer is apply LOTUS to $Z=g(X,Y)$ and then discover the link between joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to the distribution of $Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z=X+Y$.  Then we can first show the Law of Unconscious Statistician holds for the sum, and then the Linearity of Expectation. $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X+Y) &= \mathsf E(Z)\\[1ex] &= \int_\Bbb R z\,f_{X+Y}(z)\,\mathrm d z\tag 1\\[1ex] &=\int_\Bbb R z\int_\Bbb R f_{X,X+Y}(x, z)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d z\tag 2\\[1ex] &=\int_\Bbb Rz\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x, z-x)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d z\tag 3\\[1ex] &=\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R z\, f_{X,Y}(x, z-x)\,\mathrm d z\,\mathrm d x\tag 4\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R (x+y) f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\tag 5\\[4ex]\hline\mathsf E(X+Y) &= \int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R x\, f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x+\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\tag 6\\[1ex] &= \int_\Bbb R x\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x+\int_\Bbb R y\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\tag 7\\[1ex] &= \int_\Bbb R x\,f_{X}(x)\,\mathrm d x+\int_\Bbb R y\,f_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\tag 8\\[1ex]\therefore\qquad\mathsf E(X+Y) &= \mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(Y)\tag 9\end{align}$$

This is of course, for continuous random variables.   There are analogous proofs for discrete random variables, and so on.

Comment: This is correct both mathematically and philosophically! The simple '$Z=X+Y$' answers precisely the question of how joint density comes up, W/C CAN STILL be asked even if i know LOTUS i.e. i think each one of Michael Hardy and md5 incompletely explains/explain (grammar?) how LOTUS applies: the answer is apply LOTUS to $Z=g(X,Y)$ and then discover the link between joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to the distribution of $Z$.

Comment: i mention more in my answer. what do you think of my answer please?

Comment: Re $Z=X+Y$ are at least 2 of these 3 questions related? maybe duplicate? idk https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4159076 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2903847 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2476120

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of what some call the law of the unconscious statistician (google it).

\begin{align}
\operatorname E(g(W)) & = \int_{\mathcal X} g(x) f_W(x)\, dx \\[8pt]
& = \int_{g(\mathcal X)} x f_{g(W)}(x)\, dx.
\end{align}
There is no need to find the second integral above; it can be evaluated by evaluating the first one.

This is the case where $W=(X,Y)$ and $g(W)=X+Y.$

Comment: what? i believe the point is to understand how LOTUS for single variable applies to 2 or more variables. actually what's, like, the original here? $E[X] = \int x f_X(x) dx$ and so based on this original thing we get LOTUS $E[g(X)] = \int g(x) f_X(x) dx$. what's the original thing from w/c we get $E[g(X,Y)] = \int g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y) dA$ ?

Comment: @BCLC : The pair $(X,Y)$ is in the same role that $W$ in the abstract statement of LOTUS.

Comment: wait $Z=X+Y$ of Graham Kemp answers my question.

Comment: Michael Hardy, i mention more of the $Z=X+Y$ my answer. what do you think of my answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. I just do cw answer to expand Graham Kemp's answer.

> All the demonstrations I found of the linearity of the expectation in the continuous case

It's funny you should say 'continuous case'.

I tried looking it up on proofwiki and saw that in the article [Linearity of Expectation Function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearity_of_Expectation_Function), the continuous part indeed doesn't give a justification!

But the discrete does! The justification is [Expectation of Function of Joint Probability Mass Distribution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Function_of_Joint_Probability_Mass_Distribution). Here, the key idea of the proof here is to

1. come up with this random variable $Z=g(X,Y)$,
2. apply LOTUS to $Z$ and then
3. discover the link (see next) between the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to the distribution of $Z$.

This indeed works for continuous as with discrete. Still choose $g(x,y)=x+y$, to get what Graham Kemp did in h answer.

**What is the link exactly?** The preceding proofwiki article gives the link as [Probability Mass Function of Function of Discrete Random Variable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Mass_Function_of_Function_of_Discrete_Random_Variable) (hopefully you can come up with the continuous version). In fact [Probability Mass Function of Function of Discrete Random Variable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Mass_Function_of_Function_of_Discrete_Random_Variable) is used in the (discrete) LOTUS. See proofwiki's (discrete) LOTUS: [Expectation of Function of Discrete Random Variable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Function_of_Discrete_Random_Variable)