# When does linearizing $F(X_1,..,X_N)$ give an expectation of $F(E(X_1),...,E(X_N))$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

I've tried to prove that given N random variables $$x_1,…,x_N$$

the expectation of their transformation F (linearized to first order around the input variables' mean values)

$$ y = F(x_1,…,x_N) $$

equals

$$ η_y = F(η_{x_1},…,η_{x_N}) $$

My doubt is: **do the random variables need to be independent**? If yes, do you have an intuitive explanation for why in case of dependent random variables the previous relationship is wrong?

Here my proof. I guess that the red contribution can be neglected only if the joint probability density function can be factorized into the marginal distributions. Do you agree with me? I do not have an intuitive explanation for that.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "transformation"?  Do you just mean some function of the variables?  But $E[XY]$ is not $E[X]E[Y]$ in general.  (just take $X=Y$, non-constant, for a counterexample)

Comment: Unless $F(\mathbf x)$ is very simple, such as $a+b\sum x_i$ for some constants $a$ and $b$, then I do not see why this would be true even with independence.  With such a simple $F$, you do not need independence  as you could use linearity of expectation

Comment: @Henry I've forgot another assumption: I'm linearizing F around the mean value. I'll add it to the question description.

Comment: So you are saying $F(\mathbf x) \approx a +\sum b_i x_i$ for some constants $a$ and $\mathbf{b}$, which would be very simple.  With equality you could then apply linearity of expectation and you do not need independence.

Comment: @Henry But isn't expectation dependent on the joint probability density?

Comment: Not with simple addition, no.  Marginal distributions are enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y$ is defined by linearizing $F(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ around the mean values $(\eta_{X_1},\ldots,\eta_{X_N})$, then we are saying
$$
Y := F(\eta_{X_1},\ldots,\eta_{X_N})+\sum_{i=1}^N\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(\eta_{X_1},\ldots,\eta_{X_N})\right](X_i-\eta_{X_i}).\tag1$$
To compute the expectation of $Y$, the key is to observe that $F(\eta_{X_1},\ldots,\eta_{X_N})$ is constant, and so are the quantities $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(\eta_{X_1},\ldots,\eta_{X_N})$ for each $i=1,\ldots N$. Therefore the expectation of the expression (1) is
$$E(Y)=F(\eta_{X_1},\ldots,\eta_{X_N})+\sum_{i=1}^N\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(\eta_{X_1},\ldots,\eta_{X_N})\right]E(X_i-\eta_{X_i}),\tag2$$
by linearity of the expectation operator, regardless of the joint distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$. Finally the quantity $E(X_i-\eta_{X_i})$ equals zero by definition of $\eta_{X_i}$.

There's no need to involve the joint densities when computing the expectation of a sum. Linearity of expectation is valid for any collection of integrable random variables. You can see a proof that $E(X+Y)=E(X)+ E(Y)$ when $(X,Y)$ have joint density [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4159076/215011); notice that independence is not required.